# Reducing height of div on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div `hero` that sits at the top of the homepage. It is the full height of the viewport and there are other divs below. I have the following code to create the effect of faster scrolling over the first div due to it's size:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var h = $('#hero').height()
    $('#hero').height(h - 200);
});
```

but as I've changed the height of the div I'm not sure how to change the div back to it's original height when the user scrolls back to the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in JQuery ,

```
 var div = $('#hero') ;
 var divHeight = $('#hero').height() ;
 var scroll ;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    scroll = $(this).scrollTop() ;
    div.height(divHeight - scroll) ; 
});
```

Comment: Yes ! `$(document).ready(function()` only tells you that load the jquery I am writing once the DOM has been loaded ! on the other hand `window` refers to your browser window, and it'll take care of scrolling !

Comment: It doesn't quite work. The `#hero` div is growing slightly every time I scroll up and down the page

Comment: Would try this and let me know !?

Comment: This is a little better but is missing the 200 setting which is quite important for my setup

Comment: create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net .